# Set a maximum sizehint for a specific column in a table

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview

I have the following table (presented with `QTableView`, and uses a `QAbstractTableModel` derived class as a table model):

[image]

As you can see, some columns take too much space, such as the "Bitrate" or "Length" cloumns. How can I set a sizehint for a specific column, or somehow limit it's maximum size?

I've tried using `horizontalHeader`'s `setMinimumSectionSize`, but it seems to have no effect on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `setColumnWidth` of `QTableView`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#setColumnWidth

Answer (score 1):

`resizeColumnToContents` in `QTableView` is used to resize the given column based on the size hints of the delegate used to render each item in the column.

```
void QTableView::resizeColumnToContents ( int column )
```

Using this only visible columns will be resized.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#resizeColumnToContents